# kafka avro schema - 500 internal server error after 1000 messages

Tags: kafka-producer-api

I am using confluent 0.9 rest proxy and schema registry to produce avro messages in a topic.
I am using "kafka-rest" node module. After 1000 messages it starts giving 500 internal server error. After reading though some posts I understand that this error is related to a setting for max number for subjects that can be registered for a topic and reusing the schema is the solution for it.

kafka-rest documentation says the schema reuse is done transparently. Below is the sample code I used to test. I am still getting the same error.

Could someone help me understand how I can reuse the schema?

Thanks,
Rajesh

```
"use strict";
var async = require('async');
var kafkaRest = require('kafka-rest');
var topicName = "avro-test";

var valueSchema = new kafkaRest.AvroSchema({
    "name": "UserInfo",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "id", "type": "int" },
        { "name": "name", "type": "string" }]
});


var kafka = new kafkaRest({"url": "http://localhost:8082"});
var target = kafka.topic(topicName);

// Avro key and value schema.
for(var i = 0; i <= 1005; i++) {
 var line = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bob '};
 target.produce(valueSchema, line, handleResponse);

}
function handleResponse( err, res) {
 if (err) {
      console.log("Error producing messages " + err);
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a fix is coming in soon https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-node/issues/21

Meanwhile, we are using the schema Id to produce messages